# using map to create a new array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

I have the following array

```
personality_types = ["bad", "good", "great"]
```

I want to iterate through personality_types and construct(also output it) this array: `["bad person", "good person", "great person"]`

I have done it this way

```
personality_types = ["bad", "good", "great"]

personality_types.each do |x|
    x << ' person'

end

puts personality_type
```

but I want to be able to do it using the .map function instead. How can I use .map to do this? I haven't been able to figure it out.

This is what I have, but it's not working(I only get ["bad", "good", "great"] as my output):

```
personality_types = ["bad", "good", "great"]

personality_types.map { |type| 
    type + " person" 
    }


puts personality_types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#map` returns a *new* array. You have to assign it to the variable:

```
personality_types = ["bad", "good", "great"]
personality_types = personality_types.map { |type| "#{type} person" }
```

Or use [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map-21) to directly change the array:

```
personality_types = ["bad", "good", "great"]
personality_types.map! { |type| "#{type} person" }

personality_types
#=> ["bad person", "good person", "great person"]
```